# What version of QtQuick.Controls is installed on my ubuntu system?

Tags: qt, qml, ubuntu-18.04, qtquick2

I'm running ubuntu 20.04.3, and have installed qt 5.12.8 packages with 'apt'.
I install QtQuick.Controls with:

```
sudo apt-get install qml-module-qtquick-controls
```

I need to know which version of QtQuick.Controls is installed, because if my qml file contains this:

```
import QtQuick.Controls
```

I get a runtime error:

```
qrc:/main.qml:-1 Library import requires a version
```

Now how do I know which version of QtQuick.Controls is installed?

```
apt list --installed | grep qtquick-controls
qml-module-qtquick-controls/focal,now 5.12.8-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
```

I assume that "5.12.8" refers to the Qt version, not the QtQuick.Controls version.  [This page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-index.html) indicates that QtQuick.Controls version 2.12 comes with Qt 5.12. However "import QtQuick.Controls 2.12" results in this error at runtime:

```
qrc:/main.qml:4 module "QtQuick.Controls" version 2.12 is not installed
```

Can someone please help me sort this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install `qml-module-qtquick-controls2` not `qml-module-qtquick-controls`. That should fix your issue.